# Checkbox value: optional or required?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes) the `value` attribute is optional except when the value of the type attribute is `radio` or `checkbox`. But it doesn't seem to be correct. Is there anything wrong with the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="input">
<script>
    document.getElementById('input').onchange = function () {
        alert('Checked!');
    };
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hV9F2/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` attribute is only required if you want the checkbox to post through a value when you submit a form. If you're not submitting a form but just want to know when it's clicked, then there's nothing wrong with your example.

Note that your example will also alert "Checked!" when the user un-checks the box too. That's why you might also want to look at the value of the `checked` attribute in your Javascript.

Comment: "_Note that your example will also alert "Checked!" when the user un-checks the box too._" `Checked!` is just an example. It could be `Clicked!` or `'Hello, world!`. Anyway the MDN reference needs to be corrected to include your _if_. The article writer should notice the fact that we don't always use a `checkbox` in a form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox you may check for the 'checked' propoerty is true or false  since checkbox is always used either as a flag / Boolean expression .

```
document.getElementById('input').onchange = function () {
     alert('Checked!');
    alert(document.getElementById('input').checked);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think document says that it is mandatory to have the value when you need the selected option when posted back and to know what value is selected, i am not sure how why do you think your code should not work .  In current case if you submit the form and you have to checkbox you will not come know what value is being selected.

> checkbox: A check box. **You must use the value attribute to define the value submitted by this item**. Use the checked attribute to indicate whether this item is selected. You can also use the indeterminate attribute to indicate that the checkbox is in an indeterminate state (on most platforms, this draws a horizontal line across the checkbox).